# How to remove pattern lock on android 5.0 on mu Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

I upgraded my phone nexus 4 to Android 5.0 lolly pop, it was over the air upgrade.
Before upgrading i had set pattern lock to my phone, after upgrade it is using the same but in settings/security the options to disable the pattern lock is disabled (option none).
Also swipe to unlock the device option is also disabled.
Pin, Password and Pattern are enabled. please let me know to disable the lock.

Thanks,
Harish S

Answer (score 10):

Go to **Settings >> Security >> Device Administrators.** See if anything other than Android Device Manager is checked. If something is checked, it's possible it's forcing a higher level of security.

Uncheck it if there is, and check the screen lock options again.

Also try **Settings >> Security >> Clear credentials**.